# Limit of answers per day

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there any limit to the answers that a single user may give in one day?

As far as I know and I am aware of the [reputation limit per day](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), there is no restriction to the number of answers that a user may post in a day. I am not mentioning the questions -someone may really have a lot of questions.

I am asking this because I have seen many bad, off topic, even misleading (not on purpose) answers in many different tags. Most of them are not up-voted (even if they wanted to) but they still add noise to the system.

We are all seeking of reputation but there is no meaning in posting low quality answers everywhere just in case.

Comment: "off topic answers" are not answers, please point that in comment and flag as "not an answer". Bad answers should be simply downvoted, and misleading ones - commented and downvoted. i hope you are doing that already, just making sure.

Comment: @mchar : Not sure where I ever read it, but I'm pretty sure that there is some rule like "***you can only ask 30 questions over a period of 50 days***". Maybe you want to include something like that to the end of your 2nd parg in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significant percentage of downvoted or deleted answers will get user an answer ban. So the most important limit is not by reputation. It comes from **your** actions.

"Off topic answers" are not answers, please point that in comment and flag as "not an answer". Bad answers should be simply downvoted, and misleading ones - commented and downvoted. More people doing this means faster cutting out noise.

Comment: So it's up to the community members to keep the "ground" clean, makes sense, but... I have the feeling that, most of the times you are reporting a bad - misleading answer  you have to be ready to argue, to give explanations, to waste time -we have seen this many times- and this is a pain. On the other hand by doing so, shows that someone really cares for the community's quality. Concluding, to myself, a limit to the number of answers a user may post within a day would be good, so to consider twice before he answers.
Thanks all for your answers and clarifications!

Comment: @mchar downvoting and flagging "not an answer" does not require you to argue or explain. Sure, it's nice to do if you have time and patience, and if you can, you *should* do it, but in no way it is *required*.

Comment: @mchar Also, if you would (will?) post it as a feature request, my answer would be different. Probably positive, if your proposal will be reasonable.

Comment: I didn't know that I can propose requests (officially) and I guess that my statement/proposal is quite reasonable (!) given the amount of bad answers.

Comment: @mchar just tag with [meta-tag:feature-request]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, new users (those <10 reputation) have some restrictions.

**What are the new user restrictions?**

**New users cannot:**

1. post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their
   user profile
2. contribute answers to protected questions
3. **ask or answer questions too rapidly**

You can find more info on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user

Here is the [privileges](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can post all the answers that you want. But if you find a bad answer you can flag it as very low quality